# How can I get the desired object with sql from a many-to-many relationship table?

Tags: android, many-to-many, android-room, relation

i'm android beginner developer. i am createing stationArrivalInformation App.

```
@Entity
data class StationEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val stationName: String,
    val isFavorite: Boolean = false
)

@Entity
data class SubwayEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val subwayId: Int
)

@Entity(primaryKeys = ["stationName", "subwayId"])
data class StationSubwayCrossRefEntity(
    val stationName: String,
    val subwayId: Int
)

data class StationWithSubwaysEntity(
    @Embedded val station: StationEntity,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "stationName",
        entityColumn = "subwayId",
        entity = SubwayEntity::class,
        associateBy = Junction(
            StationSubwayCrossRefEntity::class,
            parentColumn = "stationName",
            entityColumn = "subwayId"
        )
    )
    val subways: List<SubwayEntity>
)
```

i have built a data class with a many-to-many relationship.

1. station Table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6W8S.png)

2. subway Table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93EzY.png)

3. cross Ref Table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYAvM.png)

if you look at the DAO File:

```
@Dao
interface StationDao {

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM StationEntity")
    fun getStationWithSubways(): Flow<List<StationWithSubwaysEntity>>

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertStations(station: List<StationEntity>)

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertSubways(subway: List<SubwayEntity>)

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertCrossRef(refEntity: List<StationSubwayCrossRefEntity>)

    @Transaction
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertStationSubways(stationSubways: List<Pair<StationEntity, SubwayEntity>>) {
        insertStations(stationSubways.map { it.first })
        insertSubways(stationSubways.map { it.second })
        insertCrossRef(stationSubways.map { (station, subway) ->
            StationSubwayCrossRefEntity(
                station.stationName, subway.subwayId
            )
        })
    }

    @Update
    suspend fun updateStation(station: StationEntity)
}
```

```
class StationRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val stationDao: StationDao
): StationRepository {
    override val stations: Flow<List<Station>> =
        stationDao.getStationWithSubways()
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .map { stations -> stations.toStation().sortedByDescending { it.isFavorite } }
            .flowOn(dispatcher)
}
```

1. here, the result of stationDao.getStationWithSubways() is null. I referred to the Android official documentation and applied it, but I am not getting the desired result. Why?

i expected getting multiple subways at one station

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOGvR.png)

Answer (score 0):

> <Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.>
> -> how solve?

Room does not anything (according to the classes shown) about the **Station** class and thus it does not know how to handle:-

```
@Update
suspend fun updateStation(station: Station)
```

As there is no such `@Entity` annotated class.

The fix I believe is to use

```
@Update
suspend fun updateStation(station: StationEntity)
```

- if that is what you are trying to update

**However**, you will then possibly have issues due to the warning that will be in the Build log:-

```
warning: The affinity of child column (subwayId : INTEGER) does not match the type affinity of the junction child column (subwayId : TEXT). - subways in a.a.so75052787kotlinroomretrievefrommanytomany.StationWithSubwaysEntity
```

Another warning that you may wish to consider is

```
warning: The column subwayId in the junction entity a.a.so75052787kotlinroomretrievefrommanytomany.StationSubwayCrossRefEntity is being used to resolve a relationship but it is not covered by any index. This might cause a full table scan when resolving the relationship, it is highly advised to create an index that covers this column. - subwayId in a.a.so75052787kotlinroomretrievefrommanytomany.StationSubwayCrossRefEntity
```

Both will not appear if you used:-

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["stationName", "subwayId"])
data class StationSubwayCrossRefEntity(
    val stationName: String,
    //val subwayId: String
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val subwayId: Int
)
```

- commented out line left in just to show before/after

You would then have to use :-

```
@Transaction
@Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
fun insertStationSubways(stationSubways: List<Pair<StationEntity, SubwayEntity>>) {
    insertStations(stationSubways.map { it.first })
    insertSubways(stationSubways.map { it.second })
    insertCrossRef(stationSubways.map { (station, subway) ->
        StationSubwayCrossRefEntity(
            station.stationName, subway.subwayId
        )
    })
}
```

- `subway.subwayId` instead of `subway.subwayId.toString()`

> i expected getting multiple subways at one station in normal operation

You would. With the changes suggested above (and some others to run on the main thread for brevity/convenience), an appropriate @Database annotated class as per:-

```
@Database(entities = [SubwayEntity::class,StationEntity::class, StationSubwayCrossRefEntity::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getStationDao(): StationDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

And the following in an Activity, to demonstrate :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var dbInstance: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: StationDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        dbInstance = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = dbInstance.getStationDao()

        dao.insertStationSubways(listOf(Pair(StationEntity("Station1",false),SubwayEntity(1))))
        dao.insertStationSubways(listOf(Pair(StationEntity("Station1",false),SubwayEntity(2))))
        dao.insertStationSubways(listOf(Pair(StationEntity("Station1",false),SubwayEntity(3))))
        dao.insertStationSubways(listOf(Pair(StationEntity("Station2",false),SubwayEntity(4))))
        dao.insertStationSubways(listOf(Pair(StationEntity("Station2",false),SubwayEntity(5))))
        dao.insertStationSubways(listOf(Pair(StationEntity("Station2",false),SubwayEntity(6))))

        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for (sws in dao.getStationWithSubways()) {
            sb.clear()
            for (subway in sws.subways) {
                sb.append("\n\tSubway is ${subway.subwayId}")
            }
            Log.d("DBINFO","Station is ${sws.station.stationName} it has ${sws.subways.size} subways. They are:-${sb}")
        }
    }
}
```

Then the log (when run for the first time) includes (as expected):-

```
D/DBINFO: Station is Station1 it has 3 subways. They are:-
        Subway is 1
        Subway is 2
        Subway is 3
D/DBINFO: Station is Station2 it has 3 subways. They are:-
        Subway is 4
        Subway is 5
        Subway is 6
```

Comment: Thank you!! i mistaked subwayId type of SubwayEntity, parameter of updateStation function.
But yet, stationDao.getStationWithSubways() return null..
I have attached an image above

Comment: @yuji As you can see it all works other than that Flow wasn't used above. I can't help with Flow but it would appear that that is where the issue is (I just deal with Room issues). Perhaps add the `.allowMainThreadQueries()` (temporarily) and have the same query but without the Flow (as per the answer) and invoke this to see what the results are. My guess is that the result isn't being collected/observed and hence it is null.